# How can I extract text layout in the correct order from a PDF file uing iText in C#

Tags: c#, itext

I know how I can extract text formatting from a PDF using as it is explained in [Extract fontname, size, style from pdf with iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133934/extract-fontname-size-style-from-pdf-with-itext) .
I even know how I can etract text with the right order as it is explained in [iText7 reading out lines in a wrong order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820361/itext7-reading-out-lines-in-a-wrong-order) .
However, it is not easy at all to extract text formatting in the correct order.

In other words, how can I use two strategies when I am extracting text in iText?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Docotic.Pdf instead. All of the formatting issues I spent hours working on with no resolution in iText7 were not issues at all when I switch to Docotic.Pdf. No wonky configs or poor documentation. It just works!